# How Would I get the value that is displayed in output, and set it as a variable?

Tags: javascript, html

How Would I get the value that is displayed in output, and set it as a variable so that way I can multiply it by another variable?

```js
let calculate = () => {
    let box1_selection = getValueById("pattern");
    let box2_selection = getValueById("thick");

    if (box1_selection == "" || box2_selection == "") {
        document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = "Please select both values";
    } else {
        let value = "not specified";

        /*if(box2_selection == 0 && box3_selection == 0 {
            value = "$27.00";
        } else if(box2_selection == 0 && box3_selection == 1) {
            value = "$17.00";
        }*/
        var lolm = getPrice(box1_selection, box2_selection);

        document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = lolm;
    }
}

var getValueById = (id) => {
    var selection = document.getElementById(id);
    return selection.options[selection.selectedIndex].value;
}

var getPrice = (value_1, value_2) => {
    // price_data is a 3 dimensional array.
    var price_data = [
        [
            [8.00],
            [13.50]
        ],
        [
            [20.80],
            [22.05]
        ],
        [
            [53.10],
            [99]
        ],
        [
            [20.20],
            [99]
        ],
        [
            [24.00],
            [99]
        ],
        [
            [99],
            [99]
        ],
        [
            [15.23],
            [99]
        ]
    ];
    return price_data[value_1][value_2];

    var roundedvalue1 = Math.ceil(document.getElementById('box3').value);
    var roundedvalue2 = Math.ceil(document.getElementById('box4').value);
    if (roundedvalue1 % 2 != 0) {
        roundedvalue1 += 1;
    }

    if (roundedvalue2 % 2 != 0) {
        roundedvalue2 += 1;
    }
    var result = document.getElementById('result');
    var rounded1plus2 = (roundedvalue1 + 2)
    var rounded2plus2 = (roundedvalue2 + 2)
    var squareFoot = (rounded1plus2 * rounded2plus2 / 144)
    var myResult = +lolm;
    result.value = myResult;
}
```

```html
<select id="pattern" onchange="calculate()">
        <option value="">Select Glass Pattern</option>
        <option value="0">Clear</option>
        <option value="1">Starphire</option>
        <option value="2">Bamboo</option>
        <option value="3">Rain</option>
        <option value="4">Satin Etch</option>
        <option value="5">MasterCarre</option>
        <option value="6">Rolled Glue Chip</option>
    </select>
<select id="thick" onchange="calculate()">
        <option value="">Select Glass Thickness</option>
        <option value="0">3/8 (10mm)</option>
        <option value="1">1/2 (12mm)</option>
    </select>
<td><input id="box3" type="text" oninput="calculate()" placeholder="Whole #'s" maxlength="3" size="4" /></td>
<td><input id="box4" type="text" oninput="calculate()" placeholder="Whole #'s" maxlength="3" size="4" /></td>
<td><b>$</b><input id="result" maxlength="4" size="4" />Flat</td>
<br>
<div id="output">Please select both values</div>
<div>

</div>
```

Essentially what I'm looking to do is to grab the output that is displayed on the webpage as actual text, set is equal to a variable that changes with the selection, that I can multiply by other variables in other parts of the script.

Comment: Didnt understand your requirement. Can you elaborate more?

Comment: Why would you want to _get_ or _grab_ `output`'s value? You're _setting_ it, it's equal to `lolm` so you already have it.

Comment: @JeremyThille @Sravan  I'm not able to grab the data from that var and multiply it by another variable to show up as an output in another part of the program I have set up, every time I use `lolm` It creates a value which is not a number, despite the given output displayed on the page being a number.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not fully understanding what you want. Here's my solution, if that helps.

You're already getting the output value in this line

```
var lolm = getPrice(box1_selection, box2_selection);`
```

It's already set to `lolm`. You can manipulate is as you like.

You've declared `lolm` inside the `calculate` arrow function as `var lolm`. So it's function scoped, if you want to access it outside the function (to use it in other functions) declare the variable `lolm` globally (outside the function).

Comment: I'm not able to use that var and multiply it by another var to show up as an output in another part of the program I have set up. Everytime I use `lolm` It generates a value which is not a number, despite the fact that the given output displayed elsewhere on the page **is** a number.

Comment: declare `lolm` outside the function and initialise it with `0` or something. as `var lolm = 0`.